# Retrieving a Sales Order programatically using OrderRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)

Tags: magento2, php, shipment

Unfortunately I find myself in a bit of difficulty. The company I work for has developed a Magento 2 extension that reads data from our proprietary software on a schedule and updates Products/Customers etc on a Magento 2 site. Unfortunately, the person who wrote the extension left the business and the ownership has been put onto me to make an enhancement to this extension.

Please be kind, I have never ever programmed in PHP or used Magento 2 before, but I find myself being given only a few days to deliver an enhancement for a customer who uses this extension.

I've been asked to programatically ship an order and apply a tracking number. After doing some research online and piecing together snippets of code, I have the following half complete function:

```
private function insertTrackingNumber($data)
    {
        $success = true;

        try {
            //$searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('increment_id', $data->SalesOrderId, 'eq')->create();

            // $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->setField('increment_id')
            // ->setValue($data->SalesOrderId)
            // ->setConditionType('eq')
            // ->create();

            $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('increment_id', '000000001')
            ->create();

            $orderList = $this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();

            // $orderList is now an array of Orders with this incrementId, which is just one order obviously

            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
            $order = $orderList[0];
            // Your logic here
            //$order = $this->_orderRepository->save($order);

            // Check if order can be shipped or has already shipped
            if (! $order->canShip()) {
                if ($this->_helper->getEnableLogging($this->_currentWebsite->getCode())) {
                    $this->_logger->warning('You cant create a shipment for this sales order.');
                }
                return false;
            }

            $shipment = $_convertOrder->toShipment($order);

            // Loop through order items
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
                // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
                if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }

                $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

                // Create shipment item with qty
                $shipmentItem = $_convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);

                // Add shipment item to shipment
                $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
            }

            // Register shipment
            $shipment->register();

            $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

            try {
                // Save created shipment and order
                $shipment->save();
                $shipment->getOrder()->save();

                // // Send email
                // $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
                //     ->notify($shipment);

                $shipment->save();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                if ($this->_helper->getEnableLogging($this->_currentWebsite->getCode())) {
                    $this->_logger->warning('Failed to save shipment: '.$e->getMessage());
                }
            }


        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($this->_helper->getEnableLogging($this->_currentWebsite->getCode())) {
                $this->_logger->warning('Failed to create shipment: '.$e->getMessage());
            }
        }


        return $success;
    }
```

`$data` is an object, with a property called `SalesOrderId` which should match the `increment_id` in Magento. However, I keep getting an error on this line:

`$order = $orderList[0];`

saying: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` which I presume is because the array is empty.

I have tried a few different methods of using the `SearchCriteriaBuilder` as you can see I have commented them out in the code. I have even resorted to hardcoding the value of the `increment_id` which I know for sure does exist and it still doesn't return anything.

Please could someone point me in the right direction? I apologise if there is a really simple solution for this but I am incredibly inexperienced with PHP and Magento and have been dropped in the deep end with this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct all of `getItems()` i guess that use below logic

**Below code**

```
   $orderList = $this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
     $order = $orderList[0];
```

**Replace by**

```
 $searchResult = $this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)
if ($searchResult->getTotalCount() >= 0) {
        $orderList = $searchResult->getItems();

        $order = $orderList[0]; // OR  use current($orderList);
}else{
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your response. The issue i'm having is that the array is empty and I don't understand why. Do you know why the getList($searchCriteria)->getItems(); method i'm using is returning an empty array? Especially since i'm passing in a valid increment_id in my $searchCriteria